# Ruby/Rails gem for picking multiple items from a list

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, picker

I assume that most of us have seen the style of "item picker" where there is a list of items in a box to one side; some arrows buttons in between, and another box on the other side, which contains the "picked" items.

Like so:

```
Picked               Available
+----------+         +-------+
| item1    |    <=   | item2 |
| item3    |   =>    | item4 | 
+----------+         | item5 | 
                     | ...   |
                     + ------+
```

Is there a gem which does this for me?

It should work 100% browser side with minimal fuss on the server side. The number of items is limited, so scrolling, AJAX paging or whatever is not required. The list of available items will be sent with the form; the list of picked items can be returned with the submit in whatever way the gem seems best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this Jquery Plugin named as **DualListBox**

https://github.com/Geodan/DualListBox

Comment: While not being as integrated as one could imagine, this worked well in the end. It requires some editing (it makes several assumptions about the bootstrap environment, has hard-coded english labels and such), but nothing too bad. Thank you!